# InHTML on button click how to fill dropdown box by JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, html

suppose Button is for subject
then dropdown should load topics of that subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can you please try this:**

```
$($.parseJSON(data.msg)).map(function () {
    return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
}).appendTo('#combobox');
```

Here's the distinction between ajax and getJSON (from the jQuery documentation):

[getJSON] is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Phoenix..the above is just a way to achieve.not exact functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should call ajax on button click & then a drop down create when ajax response generated in JSON
Fell free to Ask me if any problem